# Updating an array (passed as parameter) inside a C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I have the following declaration and function call:

```
unsigned int myArray[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
ModifyArray(&myArray[0]);
```

The above code cannot be modified, it is given as is.

I need to write the implementation for ModifyArray to update myArray to contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I have written it as:

```
void ModifyArray(unsigned int * out_buffer) 
{
  unsigned int updatedValues[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  updatedValues[0] = 1;
  updatedValues[1] = 2;
  updatedValues[2] = 3;
  updatedValues[3] = 4;
  updatedValues[4] = 5;
  *out_buffer = &updatedValues;
}
```

This doesn't really seem to work. I have a feeling that I'm not doing the assignment correctly on the last line of code, however I have tried multiple variations, and it still doesn't seem to update just element 0 of the array.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

P.S.: Please note that the scenario is more complex than presented here. I have simplified for readability purposes, but the code should look very similar to this, just the last assignment should be updated to a correct one if possible.

Comment: `*out_buffer = &updatedValues;` You need to copy the new values to the old array. But really, there's no need for `updatedValues` at all. Just use `out_buffer` directly.

Comment: Why don't you just sets the values directly to the elements of `out_buffer`?

Comment: Either just set the updated values directly to the `out_buffer` without the detour through `updatedValues`, or use `std::memcpy`. Also keep in mind that your function needs to know the array length.

Comment: You cannot assign a C-style array. (you can copy one using any number of methods, but `=` is not one of them). It isn't clear why you need an intermediate array though.  "My code is more complex" is not a valid excuse.

Comment: *"The above code cannot be modified"* Sad, as signature is bad `(unsigned int * out_buffer, int size)` or `unsigned int (& out)[5]` or `std::span<unsigned int, 5>` would be better.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you  can initialize an array directly with the desired values; `unsigned int updatedValues[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, that did the trick. I definitely tried that before, and it didn't work, however, now that it works, there must have been an error in the testing environment rather than the code! Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 This is the code they sent us for testing, this is the code we need to test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*out_buffer` is an `unsigned int`.
`&updatedValues` is an `unsigned int(*)[5]` - a pointer to an array of five elements - which you can't assign to an `int`.

You should not assign any arrays (it's impossible), you should modify the contents of the given array:

```
void ModifyArray(unsigned int *out_buffer) 
{
    out_buffer[0] = 1;
    out_buffer[1] = 2;
    out_buffer[2] = 3;
    out_buffer[3] = 4;
    out_buffer[4] = 5;
}
```

which you can simplify to

```
void ModifyArray(unsigned int *out_buffer) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        out_buffer[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first implementation is the one I need. Definitely tried that before, however I may have accidentally run the WRONG test case :D Anyways, it works now! Thank you!